# Error run flutter project in IOS - Error (Xcode): Target debug_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Binary

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am getting the error below when compiling Flutter projects (I have already created a project from scratch and I have the same error). I started having this error after deleting some files to free up space on my Mac.

I have already reinstalled Xcode because I didn't know what else to do, I searched the entire internet for a solution but I didn't find anything.

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 in debug mode...
> main.dart:1
> Xcode build done.                                            2,8s
> Failed to build iOS app
> Error (Xcode): Target debug_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Binary /Users/lucasbarreto/developer/test_compile/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework/Flutter does not exist, cannot thin
> Could not build the application for the simulator.
> Error launching application on iPhone 14.
> Exited

My flutter doctor settings:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64, locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 3.10.6 on channel stable at /Users/lucasbarreto/fvm/versions/3.10.6
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f468f3366c (4 weeks ago), 2023-07-12 15:19:05 -0700
    • Engine revision cdbeda788a
    • Dart version 3.0.6
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/lucasbarreto/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.0)
    • VS Code at /Users/lucasbarreto/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.70.0

[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.0-insider)
    • VS Code at /Users/lucasbarreto/Visual Studio Code - Insiders.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.71.20230801

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 14 (mobile) • 53A0CEA2-8655-43A6-9523-78D5C99569AD • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4
      (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)    • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 115.0.5790.170

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

Comment: Did you found any solution? It happened to me using any IDE expect in Xcode, too weird! Idk what more else to do!

Comment: My solution was to give flutter upgrade switching to the latest version. You can also test by going to the latest unstable version.

Comment: I realize that there is a bug with cloud sync folders even if you use .noSync (in iCloud's case) so you just need to move your desired project to a non sync folder and everything will work properly with the latest version of flutter and Xcode beta 6 

Answer (score 0):

Just change the flutter directory where you put the flutter.
And also change your path in Android Studio.

1. Change the flutter path
2. AndroidStudio -> Settings -> Dart (Change the path) -> Flutter (Change the path)